# Is it possible to undo an 'svn checkout'

Tags: svn

I've search through the suggested questions about my issue, but nothing looks like its an answer to the issue that I'm having.

I (foolishly) ran 'svn checkout http_file_path_to_server', which modified everything I had been working on locally.

Is there any way to revert the checkout and restore my files to the previous local versions? I had not made any commits.

Comment: So, you're saying `svn checkout` overwrote your local uncommitted changes?  SVN makes it pretty hard to do that, are you sure that was the result?

Comment: @Joe, has it right, SVN won't overwrite your local changes.  I just tried this on the Linux command line and while is says it did the checkout, my local changes were still present.

Comment: Yes, I have 5 files that my lead had to modify to get the app running properly, and all 5 have the 'U' signifier from the checkout. Even the senior devs here have told me that I'm screwed at this point.
Yay for jr mistakes.

Comment: @lopac1029 that means that there were changes that were made to the files you had updated, after you pulled your working copy. It should have merged those files with yours, not overwrote.

Comment: Unless they caused conflicts, which preserve your code, but you'll have to edit/resolve indeed, with little hassle. Unless someone chose an `accept-theirs`...

Comment: Oh, and I think the answer is no to "Can you undo a svn checkout".  Similar to the fact that you can't undo an unzip without manually deleting each file that is unpacked from the archive, unless your operating system has an advanced undo feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse's local history...where are files saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969782/eclipses-local-history-where-are-files-saved)

Comment: @lopac1029 No it is not possible :D :D :D