# Java files disappeared in Eclipse after exporting

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a project in Eclipse that has several classes and one Interface. I decided to export it as a jar so that I can run it on another machine.

This went just fine. However, when I went back to Eclipse, it suddenly removed all of my file one by one as soon as I tried to edit one of them. Now there is only one file left and it's not even my main. I had everything in the default workspace directory and now only that one file remains.

Can I undo it?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just a bug with eclipse? As in, have you tried looking in your workspace directory to see if the files are actually deleted?

Comment: There was a similar report a couple of days ago here on this site. Try searching here. I don't recall their suggestion. Hope you can recover!

Comment: @Natecat That's part of the problem... It's not in workspace directory anymore either. There is only that one file left out of like 8.

Comment: @KevinO Thanks! I wasn't able to find anything by Googling around though. I'll try looking more specifically on here. If anyone has the direct link to the issue, please let me know!

Comment: For now just check your trash.. at least data can be recovered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305458/restore-deleted-files-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: @Bhavesh It's not in the Recycle Bin either...

Comment: are you using any version controller like git or svn

Comment: Thank you for the link! It helped recover most of them! I didn't use a source control (the project isn't that big), but I do have some older copies of the files on a usb drive. Luckily, the files that are not recoverable have not been modified and I can just take them from the usb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar just happened to me a while ago, Eclipse has the option to recover files no matter if you have a version control or not...

make right click in the project and make a "**Restore from local history**"

a new window with all accidentally removed files will appear and you can undo the mess :)

[image]