# How to recover deleted java files on a mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, data-recovery

Using Eclipse I accidentally deleted the wrong folder on my file system and lost hundreds of java files on my mac yesterday.

I am using a second mac to connect to my mac via firewire.
My mac appears as an external disk on the second mac.
I am running data recovery programs on the second mac to ensure that none of the deleted files are overwritten by writes to the file system on my mac.

I've tried a couple data recovery programs (Disk Drill, Data Rescue 3), but they don't seem to be able to recognize .java files.

Has anyone had a good experience recovering deleted .java files on a mac?

Comment: I'm assuming you already checked the Trash. The files were not in there?

Comment: I assume that 'restore from latest backups' would not be welcome?

Comment: I payed $89 for disk drill which didn't work, then the company said it's my own fault for purchasing it without predicting whether the recovery would be successful. Buyer Beware.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse usually keeps internal history. You should be able to restore the files using Eclipse itself, if the files were deleted in Eclipse: **In context menu of you project you should see "Restore from Local History.." item**.

On the other hand I would recommend to always use SCM tools (such as Git, Mercural etc). This way you will never lose your code. Practially every SCM tool this days has a very good Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Unfortunately the eclipse projects have actually been deleted.
However, these suggestions did point to a solution that worked for me ...

It seems that Eclipse makes backups of every file that you work on in the following location:
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
The files can be manually recovered one by one.

Discovered this on stack overflow post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969782/eclipses-local-history-where-are-files-saved

Comment: Good to know. Now make sure you use SCM. Even for personal projects. Bitbucket.org is a perfect solution if you need free private repositories. It supports both Git and Mercurial

Comment: thank you so much!!!! tomorrow is my project deadline and I accidentally deleted a file, you are my savior!!! you saved me et least 2-3 hours of work!!!